# Django numeric comparison of hstore or json data?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, hstore

Is it possible to filter a queryset by casting an hstore value to `int` or `float`?

I've run into an issue where we need to add more robust queries to an existing data model.  The data model uses the `HStoreField` to store the majority of the building data, and we need to be able to query/filter against them, and some of the values need to be treated as numeric values.

However, since the values are treated as strings, they're compared character by character and results in incorrect queries. For example, `'700' > '1000'`.

So if I want to query for all items with a sqft value between 700 and 1000, I get back zero results, even though I can plainly see there are hundreds of items with values within that range.  If I just query for items with sqft value >= 700, I only get results where the sqft value starts with 7, 8 or 9.

I also tried testing this using a JsonField from `django-pgjson` (since we're not yet on Django 1.9), but it appears to have the same issue.

**Setup**

```
Django==1.8.9
django-pgjson==0.3.1 (for jsonfield functionality)
Postgres==9.4.7
```

**models.py**

```python
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField
from django.db import models

class Building (models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    data = HStoreField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**Example Data**

This is an example of what some of the data on the hstore field looks like.

```
address1: ...
address2: ...
city: ...
state: ...
zipcode: ...
data: {
    'year_built': '1995',
    'building_type': 'residential',
    'building_subtype': 'single-family',
    'bedrooms': '2',
    'bathrooms': '1',
    'total_sqft': '958',
}
```

**Example Query which returns incorrect results**

```
queryset = Building.objects.filter(data__total_sqft__gte=700)
```

I've tried playing around with the `annotate` feature to see if I can coerce it to cast to a numeric value but I have not had any luck getting that to work.  I always get an error saying the field I'm querying against does not exist. This is an example I found elsewhere which doesn't seem to work.

```
queryset = Building.objects.all().annotate(
    sqft=RawSQL("((data->>total_sqft)::numeric)")
).filter(sqft__gte=700)
```

Which results in this error:

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'sqft' into field. Choices are: address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, data

One thing that complicates this setup a little further is that we're building the queries dynamically and using `Q()` objects to and/or them together.

So, trying to do something sort of like this, given a key, value and operator type (`gte`, `lte`, `iexact`):

```
queryset.annotate(**{key: RawSQL("((%data->>%s)::numeric)", (key,)})
queries.append(Q(**{'{}__{}'.format(key, operator): value})
queries.filter(reduce(operator.and_, queries)
```

However, I'd be happy even just getting the first query working without dynamically building them out.

I've thought about the possibility of having to create a separate model for the building data with the fields explicitly defined, however there are over 600 key value pairs in the `data` hstore.  It seems like changing that into a concrete data model would be a nightmare to setup and potentially maintain.

Comment: I've been able to get the queries working by upgrading Django and using the built in `JSONField` in 1.9 instead of `django-pgjson` since it uses the `jsonb` instead of `json` database field.  However it still seems like it should be possible to do this using the standard json field.

Comment: Single quotes around total_sqft? As in: RawSQL("((data->>'total_sqft')::numeric)"). Maybe without the inner parens too:  RawSQL("(data->>'total_sqft'::numeric)"). I don't use HStore, but that's how PostgreSQL uses it for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a very similar problem and ended up using the [Cast Function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) (Django > 1.10) with [KeyTextTransform](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26511).

```
my_query =.query.annotate(as_numeric=Cast(KeyTextTransform('my_json_fieldname', 'metadata'), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2))).filter(as_numeric=2)
```